# Runc Containerd Check pointing support

Tags: linux, docker, containers, checkpoint, runc

I found this docker tool that used runc natively. 
[Containerd](https://github.com/docker/containerd)

I have three Questions:

1. How it Work (How it checkpoints the container)?
2. How to use it for live migration?
3. What it the functional call sequence that its implemented.

Comment: Why not read this tool documentation?

Comment: I had but i could found the questions to these answer nor the tools used to implement the check-pointing